# Found out that my question is invalid

Tags: discussion, questions, behavior, self-delete

What should I do with [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246123/asp-net-restart-assembly-reload-problem) if I found out that it is *invalid*?

For example, I have posted a question whining that something is not working, only to find out half an hour later that I was looking at the completely wrong place.

Should I simply delete the question, flag it as invalid, or something else?

**[Edit]** Why I am asking is because I actually consider parts of the question to be informative (at least for my own future reference). So I thought deleting it would not be the best option of all.

Comment: You should delete it if possible.  Otherwise, add an answer of your own explaining how you solved the problem, and accept that.

Comment: You can also flag for a moderator and request for it to be deleted, if you can't delete it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the question you asked represents a possible real problem, edit in a little note to the extent that you seem to have been mistaken, but leave the question and vote for good answer to it. *It will be available as a resource in the future.*
- If the question describes a seemingly impossible situation that you've just discovered doesn't actually obtain, you are probably best deleting it. If you can't edit to admit to the situation so that other won't spend a lot of time trying to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "flag as invalid". If you think it's something that could happen to someone else, post an answer on your own question and accept it. If it's a one-time thing and this question wouldn't help anyone else (which is what it sounds like in this case), just delete it

Answer (score 1):

If you have 250 reputation, the best thing to do is probably delete it. If you don't have 250 rep yet, the best thing then is probably to just flag it.